# CREATE TABLE command is not working in Hive query language

Tags: hadoop, hive, metastore, apache-hive

When I try to create a table in hive getting the following error message. Any idea why this is happening?

```
hive> create table a (x int);
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)

Following were the logs:

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate key name 'TBLS_FK2' at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorA‌​ccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the hive logs?Also which metastore are you using derby or mysql?

Comment: thanks for responding. I am using mysql metastore. the log file created under /tmp/username with extension .pipeout is empty. Is there way to enable logging

Comment: Following is snapshot of the log: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Duplicate key name 'TBLS_FK2'
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

Comment: Can you try stopping the hive server and login to mysql and delete the metastore and start the server again.I think there might be some old metastore which was not properly upgraded in mysql or the metastore tables were not properly created

Comment: This link might help you http://qnalist.com/questions/5919571/hive-1-1-0-error-while-metastore-starting

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

Its mandatory to initialize the schema with SCHEMA TOOL

Command: $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema

Note: In your case -dbType is mysql if you are using mysql as rdbms.

please refer the below link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool